# Using select with cast to do time calculations

Tags: sql, date, select, time

I'm doing a select of different date and time fields, and want to calculate the difference between them in fractions of an hour.  I'm using the datediff to get the difference in minutes, but when I divide by 60, I'm not getting a fraction.

Tried cast as decimal and real

```
select 
      ,[Call_Date]
      ,[Call_Time]
      ,convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), call_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Call_time, 108)) as Call_DT
      ,[Roll_Time_Date]
      ,[Roll_Time_Time]
      ,convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), Roll_time_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Roll_time_time, 108)) as Roll_DT
      ,cast(datediff(mi, (convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), call_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Call_time, 108))),
                      (convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), Roll_time_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Roll_time_time, 108))))/60 as decimal)
       As Downtime 
FROM [MFSQL_DTFM].[dbo].[MFWorkOrder] where Customer='Joe'
```

Sample Data:

```
Call_Date   Call_Time   Call_DT    Roll_Time_Date          Roll_Time_Time Roll_DT   Downtime
2019-04-01  15:39:00    2019-04-01 15:39:00.000 2019-04-02  13:01:00     2019-04-02 13:01:00.000    21
2019-04-01  15:54:00    2019-04-01 15:54:00.000 2019-04-01  17:10:00     2019-04-01 17:10:00.000    1
2019-04-01  16:15:00    2019-04-01 16:15:00.000 2019-04-01  21:30:00     2019-04-01 21:30:00.000    5
```

Comment: Could you add your expected output? I do not understand what you want from your query.

Comment: For this snippet, I want the (roll_date&roll_time) - (call_date&call_time) expressed as a decimal fraction of an hour.  For example if call date/time were 2019-01-01 at 00:01:00, and roll date/time were 2019-01-02 at 00:01:30, I'd expect the result to be 24.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 60 AS Decimal to 60.0

This will make the value decimal by default instead of having to convert from int.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
with mainTimes as (
  select
    Call_Date
   ,Call_Time
   ,convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), call_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Call_time, 108)) as Call_DT
   ,Roll_Time_Date
   ,Roll_Time_Time
   ,convert(DATETIME, convert(char(8), Roll_time_date, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(8), Roll_time_time, 108)) as Roll_DT
  from [MFSQL_DTFM].[dbo].[MFWorkOrder]
  where Customer='Joe'
)
select *,
  datediff(mi,Call_DT,RollDT)/60.0 as Downtime
from mainTimes
```